# Getting error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet while installing oauth2 provider in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I am trying to install  django-oauth2-provider in Django. After installing and configuring settings.py, during migrations, I am getting the error like:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'hello_api',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'provider',
    'provider.oauth2',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'hello_api2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Error Traceback :

```
error: File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/oauth2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import backends
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/oauth2/backends.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .forms import ClientAuthForm, PublicPasswordGrantForm
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/oauth2/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import Client, Grant, RefreshToken
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/provider/oauth2/models.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Client(models.Model):
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ravi/PycharmProjects/hello-api2/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Don't use `django-oauth2-provider` it has not been updated in 3 years and that is what is likely causing the issue. Keep looking for a new package that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `django-oauth2-provider` as it is no longer maintained. With the last update being 3 years ago.

The traceback you provided is in their bug reports for Django 1.9+.

https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider/issues/136

However you can use   **Django OAuth Toolkit** which provides all the similar and enhanced functionalities and also supports Django >= 1.8.For more information,  [read from here](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit).

And for comparison between them,you can use [this source](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/oauth/).

Comment: I'm happy to hear and sorry that I do not know of a good project to suggest.

Comment: I will update my answer if I come across one or one is suggested.

Comment: @EmettSpeer There are many. Python social auth is one of them.

Comment: @Ravi Did you try my solution?

Comment: Would you be willing to edit my answer with the details and I will approve them. I have not used social auth before.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Edited your answer.